# Android strings Localisation working partially

Tags: java, android, xml, string, localization

I am trying to use Localisation in my app where I am using 3 languages, when I switch languages not all strings are being translated, some strings are displayed in English only whatever language I switch to.

This is the code I am using which is working partially:

```
public void setLocale_language(String lang) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(config, dm);
}
```

Comment: Can you include code for some of those problematic strings? I'd guess you're using a wrong `Context` to access them (say, `Application` instead of `Activity` that has been wrapped with your resource overrides).

Comment: @laalto actually these strings are accessed from `xml` layout like so `android:text="@string/clocked_in_users"`

Comment: XML inflation also requires a Context (via LayoutInflater)

Comment: I found the mistake ): my `Activity` was extending `FragmentActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity` this was the reason why strings were not translated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the activity was extending `FragmentActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`

```
public class Dashboard extends FragmentActivity
```

So changing it to `AppCompatActivity` solved this issue

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity
```